# Does each new client connection create a new Channel?

Tags: java, netty

New to netty here. But my question here is: when we establish a connection from a client to server, would this create a new Channel for each new connection. Would this also subsequently create an associated pipeline for each new client connection. (e.g. would 100 clients that are simultaneously connected to a server create 100 individual channels with 100 associated pipelines?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thats exactly how it works. Each connection will be a new Channel with its own ChannelPipeline etc